# Can anyone explain this formula graphically?

Tags: kinematics

$$v^2=u^2+2as$$
v=final velocity; u=initial velocity, a=acceleration; s=displacement. I know and understand how this equation is derived.But, can anyone show me that $v^2=u^2+2as$ using graphic materials like graph?

Comment: Assuming $v, u$ are your coordinates, then $v^2-u^2=const.$ defines a set of hyperbolas. In Wolfram Alpha you can plot them with e.g. "contour plot v^2-u^2"

Answer (score 1):

the areas of two rectangles are equal, and the sides are proportional:

LHS rectangle with sides:  $(v+u)$ and $(v-u)$, -- from $(v^2-u^2)$
RHS rectangle with sides: $\sqrt{2}$ boosted by acceleration and displacement: $(a)$ and $(s)$

for simplicity assume $v>u$ and displacement $s$ as dependent on acceleration $a$, rearranging

$(v+u)(v-u)=\sqrt{2}a\cdot\sqrt{2}s$
and then relating the sides of the rectangles one to one we get:
 $(v+u)=\sqrt{2}a$  reading : the sum of final plus initial vels is proportional to acceleration
 $(v-u)=\sqrt{2}s$  reading : the difference of final minus initial vels is proportional to the displacement
the constant of proportionality is the side of a rectangle with area 2.
(or the side assignment is in the other way ? : study it yourself, iyw)